# Hibernate Fetch @Formula annotated fields on demand

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a entity (declared with 2 way)(some not influencing code part are ommited for readability)

Entity version 1.

```
@Entity 
public class Article {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Long id;

            @Column(name = "name")
            private String name;

            @Formula("(SELECT COUNT(w.id) FROM stock s LEFT JOIN warehouse w ON s.id=w.stock_id WHERE s.article_id = id)")
            private int variants; 

            public int getVariants() {
                return variants;
            }

        }
```

Entity version 2.

```
@Entity 
public class Article {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Long id;

            @Column(name = "name")
            private String name;

            @Transient
            private int variants; 

            @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
            @Formula("(SELECT COUNT(w.id) FROM stock s LEFT JOIN warehouse w ON s.id=w.stock_id WHERE s.article_id = id)")
            public int getVariants() {
                return variants;
            }

        }
```

respective DTO and ArticleMapper - MapStruct

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ArticleDTOCommon {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ArticleDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int variants;
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface ArticleMapper{
    ArticleDTO toDto(Article article);
    ArticleDTOCommon toDtoCommon(Article article);
}
```

I have a @Service layer on which how i know Hibernate creates it's proxy(for defining which field is fetch or not fetch) and transactions are occurs.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ArticleService {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<ArticleDTO> findAll() {
        return articleRepository.findAll()
            stream().map(articleMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<ArticleDTO> findAllCommon() {
        return articleRepository.findAll()
            stream().map(articleMapper::toDtoCommon).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

It works fine with fetching Related entity but
**Problem is (fetching @Formula annotated field) when I am looking executed query on log it fetchs all time variants @Formula annotated query not depending on respective DTO.**
But it must be ignored on toDtoCommon - i.e. It must not fetch variants field -> because when mapping Article to ArticleDtoCommon it not uses getVariant() field of Article. I have tried multiple ways as mentioned above.

I can solve it with writing native query(for findAllCommon() method) and map respectivelly with other way... But I want to know that how we can solve it with ORM way and where is problem.
Manupulating @Access type is not helping too.

Thanks is advance.